# Spark micro framework - save sessions in database?

Tags: java, database, session, spark-java

How do I configure a RDBMS (MySQL) as the session store for Spark Framework (the Java micro web framework as available at http://sparkjava.com/)?

The reason I ask this is that I want user sessions to remain valid if jetty, which Spark runs on, has to be restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually there is an option to store Sessions in database. I use Ebean ORM, but you can do it with any other ORM as well as with pure SQL.

Assume that we have User class and UserSession class.

What you should do is check whether there is an active session. If it already exists and has no user bound — we pass to authentication. If it does not exist — we check if `JSESSIONID` cookie exists and has a record in UserSession table. If there is such session we retrieve a User, create new session and bind user to it.

Two class listings below are pretty self-explanatory. Call `User.getAuthenticatedUser()` every time someone tries to access URI for authenticated users. Call `User.addAuthenticatedUser(req, user)` at successful login attempt.

User class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    private static final String USER_SESSION_ID = "sessionId";

    @Id
    Long id;

    String login;
    String password;
    String email;

    Integer role;

    public static User authUser(User user) {
        return Ebean.find(User.class).where()
                .eq("login", user.login)
                .eq("password", user.password)
                .findUnique();
    }

    public static void addAuthenticatedUser(Request req, User u) {
        Session session = req.session();
        Ebean.save(new UserSession(u, session.id()));
        req.session().attribute(USER_SESSION_ID, u);
    }

    public static User getAuthenticatedUser(Request req, Response res) {
        User user = null;
        Session session = req.session(false);
        if (session == null) {
            UserSession userSession = UserSession.getSession(req.cookies().get("JSESSIONID"));
            if (userSession != null) {
                user = userSession.getUser();
                userSession.delete();
                addAuthenticatedUser(req, user);
            }
        } else {
            user = session.attribute(USER_SESSION_ID);
        }

        // Redirect to login form
        if (user == null) {
            res.redirect("/login");
            halt();
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

UserSession class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "sessions")
public class UserSession {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "uid")
    private User user;
    private String session;
    private Timestamp taken;

    public UserSession(User u, String sessionId) {
        user = u;
        session = sessionId;
        taken = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    public static UserSession getSession(String session) {
        return Ebean.find(UserSession.class).where().eq("session", session).findUnique();
    }

    public void delete() {
        SqlUpdate deleteQuery = Ebean.createSqlUpdate("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE uid = :uid AND session = :session");
        deleteQuery.setParameter("uid", user.id);
        deleteQuery.setParameter("session", session);
        deleteQuery.execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The spark session API is a wrapper around the servlet HttpSession object. There is no option to configure a datbase for session storage. How sessions are stored depends on the servlet container.